# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at script.js:13

Tags: javascript, properties, null, typeerror, addeventlistener

I am stuck with the 'cannot read properties of null' type error.. I see that the page is running correctly but in the console it throws this subject line error.

```js
// const panel = document.querySelector("#panel");
const sendButton = document.querySelector('#send');
const ratingsContainer = document.querySelector('.ratings-container');
const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
const experience = document.querySelectorAll('small');

const removeActive = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
    ratings[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
};

ratingsContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('rating')) {
    removeActive();
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
  }
});

sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(experience[0]);
  for (let i = 0; i < experience.length; i++) {
    if (experience[i].innerHTML === 'Unhappy' || experience[i].innerHTML === 'Neutral') {
      document.location.href = 'negative_review.html';
    } else {
      document.location.href = 'positive_review.html';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Feedback</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="panel" class="panel-container">
            <form>
                <strong>Great! Would you like to post your review?</strong>

                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="button-link">Google</a>
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

this line is trying to find something with the class `ratings-container`:

```
const ratingsContainer = document.querySelector('.ratings-container');
```

but there's nothing in the html with that class, so the `ratingsContainer` is effeectively `null`, which has no `addEventListener` method.

Comment: this is a small snippet of the index.html page, since stackoverflow is not letting me to post the whole thing here.

Comment: <div class="ratings-container">
    <div class="rating">
     <img
      src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/742/742752.png"
      alt=""
     />
     <small>Unhappy</small>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the code is that sendButton element and ratingsContainer element are null. there are no elemnts in the html fitting the selector you wrote.
hope I was helpful.

```js
// const panel = document.querySelector("#panel");
const sendButton = document.querySelector('#send');
const ratingsContainer = document.querySelector('.ratings-container');
const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
const experience = document.querySelectorAll('small');

const removeActive = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
    ratings[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
};

ratingsContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('rating')) {
    removeActive();
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
  }
});

sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(experience[0]);
  for (let i = 0; i < experience.length; i++) {
    if (experience[i].innerHTML === 'Unhappy' || experience[i].innerHTML === 'Neutral') {
      document.location.href = 'negative_review.html';
    } else {
      document.location.href = 'positive_review.html';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Feedback</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="panel" class="panel-container">
            <form>
                <strong>Great! Would you like to post your review?</strong>

                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="button-link">Google</a>
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="send"></button>
        <div class="ratings-container"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the index html page is linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989967/how-to-redirect-button-to-the-correct-html-pages-using-if-else