# How to redirect button to the correct html pages using if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom

I have 3 html files for this page. index.html, positive review page and negative review page. I want my JavaScript to redirect to the pages after clicking the emojis feedback and then the button. After clicking the button depending on the emojis clicked it should redirect to the negative review page if the emoji selected is neutral or unhappy and if the emoji selected is satisfied to redirect to the positive review page. I am new and stuck with the below code. The below code takes me back to the positive review page.

```
const sendButton = document.querySelector("#send");
const panelContainer = document.querySelector(".panel-container");
const ratings = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");
const experience = document.querySelectorAll("small");

sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < experience.length; i++) {
        // console.log(experience[i].innerHTML);
        if (
            experience[i].innerHTML === "Unhappy" ||
            experience[i].innerHTML === "Neutral"
        ) {
            window.location = "negative_review.html";
        } else {
            window.location = "positive_review.html";
        }
    }
}); 

This is the index page only.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Feedback</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="panel" class="panel-container">
            <h2>Welcome Text</h2>
            <strong
                >How was your experience <br />
                with us?
            </strong>
            <div class="ratings-container">
                <div class="rating">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/742/742752.png"
                        alt=""
                    />
                    <small>Unhappy</small>
                </div>

                <div class="rating">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/725/725085.png"
                        alt=""
                    />
                    <small>Neutral</small>
                </div>

                <div class="rating active">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/166/166549.png"
                        alt=""
                    />
                    <small>Satisfied</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form>
                <label for="feedback">Please Tell Us About Your Experience</label>
                <textarea name="" id="" maxlength="350" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </form>
            <button class="btn" id="send">Send Review</button>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const experience = document.querySelectorAll("small");` missing the dot before `small`

Comment: more importantly, how do users select ratings? I don't see any `input` element

Comment: @GrafiCode Nope, it's a tag selector, and there are `small` tags in the markup.

Comment: ah @Teemu you're right about `<small>` tags, still, it's not clear how to "select" the rating

Comment: You could be setting some sort of state on the emojis to indicate it was selected. You could use data-* attributes, or even a simple classname like ".active". As it stands, how does your code know which one you selected? It just loops through them all.

Comment: @GrafiCode OP is trying to do it in the loop, but obviously it fails, that's the subject of the question.

Comment: @JeremyHarris can you please give me an example, as I know it is simple but still in the learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the correct experience to use is the one surrounded by `<div class="active">`

```js
sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const experience = document.querySelector(".rating.active small");
  if (
      experience[i].innerHTML === "Unhappy" ||
      experience[i].innerHTML === "Neutral"
  ) {
      window.location = "negative_review.html";
  } else {
      window.location = "positive_review.html";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution however, I tried it and it doesn't work. The problem I have is const experience = document.querySelector(".rating.active small") there are 3 ratings and 3 small tags but one active. I tried querySelectorAll and without the "all" in order to go over all 3 ratings to redirect.

Comment: .rating.active small will select all small tags that are within a ".rating .active" parent.  There should only be one.

Comment: If that's true, then your html is not as above.  Please verify there is only one div with both classes rating and active.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!    Solution: I removed the for loop as @James pointed out, the querySelector(".active small") will have all 3 small tags

Comment: yes it is exactly as above, with parent div as with the class panel-container followed by 3 divs with the class rating and the third div with the class rating active.

Comment: script.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') is the error in the console , I deleted the previous post so re writing it

Comment: I just rewrote your event listener.  I didn't guarantee that the rest of your code was bug free.  You need to define sendButton before you attach a listener.